# subdivide all faces whose area is bigger than 1mm until each face area is smaller than 1mm

Tags: subdivision-surface

I have a mesh as follows. I would like to subdivide all faces, where the area of each face is bigger than 1mm, until each of those faces has an area of no more than 1mm.

Is there a way to do that in Blender or any other software?

You can downdoad the model here https://gist.githubusercontent.com/umhan35/127041505840cf2259d98d2db37dea48/raw/45ffa8bf440fe393f0ed0913984b8cb8acf8c102/caddy.stl

Thanks!

[image: model]

Using the Dyntopo method:

[image: constant]

The problem is the long edge

[image: long edge]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with Blender. Enter Sculpt mode and set the Dyntopo resolution to 1000 (divisor by blender units) Subdivide Edges, Constant Detail and press Detail Flood Fill.

Set the Refine Mode to Subdivide Edges so it only divide edges that are longer than the wanted length but leaves shorter. In that way you can keep the geometry intact instead of loosing definition.

[image]

Comment: I append a photo in my questions. It also "scale up" the small details

Comment: Updated my answer :-)

Comment: I appended another image. The problem is that it checks the edge length, which means small-area faces can also be subdivided.

Answer (score 0):

**REMESH**

[image]

[image]

- Please see Remesh Modifier.
- It may not be exactly what you want.
- However Remesh is here now.
- In the image above some text has been converted to mesh. Then Remesh is used.  Press [Apply] to see evenly spaced faces for better beformations.
- Perfection is the enemy of Good.

Image to follow.